# Shopify buy-js-sdk metafield

Tags: shopify

I'm using the Shopify [buy-js-sdk](https://github.com/Shopify/js-buy-sdk) and I would like to get metafields.
I've exposed the custom metafield to the StoreFront API but I'm still facings the error
`Error: No field of name "dateFrom" found on type "Metafield" in schema`

original detailed question unanswered [here](https://github.com/Shopify/js-buy-sdk/issues/769)

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried getting say the first 10 metafields to see what it outputs?